# how to pas json array as parameter to other activity and display

Tags: android

Im passing json array as parameter to other activity but is show all values in text when I click, see this image on monday
http://postimg.org/image/fbjlm8y97/91beaa03/ 
is display on other activity like that http://postimg.org/image/8m0f1bjaf/987e8eb4/ 
every thing in string how do I show only name in TextView? now every thing how do I parse json array???

Json :

```
   {
   "student": [
     {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Monday",
        "dish": "Biryani",
        "Gender": "M",
        "age": 10,
        "birthdate": "23/05/2002"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Tuesday",
        "dish": "Sandwish",
        "Gender": "M",
        "age": 12,
        "birthdate": "08/01/2000"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Wednesday",
        "dish": "Chicken Tikka",
        "Gender": "F",
        "age": 14,
        "birthdate": "01/03/1998"
    },
```

Code:

```
            try {
                JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject(result);
                 jsonArray = mainJson.getJSONArray(ARRAY_NAME);
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                     objJson = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    Item objItem = new Item();

                    objItem.setId(objJson.getInt(ID));
                    objItem.setName(objJson.getString(NAME));
                    myname= objJson.getString(NAME);
                    objItem.setCity(objJson.getString(CITY));
                    objItem.setGender(objJson.getString(GENDER));
                    objItem.setAge(objJson.getInt(AGE));
                    objItem.setBirthdate(objJson.getString(BIRTH_DATE));

                    arrayOfList.add(objItem);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            setAdapterToListview();

        }

    }
 }

 @Override
 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

     if(!jsonArray.isNull(position)){
           Intent intent = new Intent(SeletecDayofweek.this,TodayLunch.class);  
           intent.putExtra("name", jsonArray.optJSONObject(position).toString());
           startActivity(intent);    
     }

}     






                   and get like this


                      Intent intent = getIntent();
    String stringRecd = intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: now how do i parse json data???like this way 
  objItem.setName(objJson.getString(NAME));
textview.settext(objJson.getString(NAME))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `putExtra("name",jsonArray.optJSONObject(position).toString());` you are storing the entire JSON Object as a string under the variable 'name', which is being parsed to the new Activity. When you get 'name' from the Intent, it the entire JSON Object that is being returned.

If you just want to send the name and not then entire string, try this `jsonArray.optJSONObject(position).getString("name")` instead of using the `toString()` method

Comment: no i want to parse all josn to other activity and diffrenciate them means in nametext print name in gender textview print text in age textview print age so how do i divide all json data to its attributes

Comment: ok, you can send the whole object, and then create a new JSON Object in the new activity and request each field as desired that way. Hope you get it working properly (Some of my favourite food's are in your array lol. )

Answer (score 0):

JSON serialises - *boing!* - you can pass it as an extra to any activity very easily.

Comment: impasing json array toother activity how do i displaythere with is attribues??

Answer (score 0):

Write a `JSONParser` class:

```
public class JSONParser
{

static InputStream is   = null;
static JSONObject  jObj = null;
static String      json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser()
{

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(
        String url ,
        String method ,
        List<NameValuePair> params )
{
    Log.d( "JSON" , "making HTTP request" );
    // Making HTTP request
    try
    {

        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST")
        {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost( url );
            httpPost.setEntity( new UrlEncodedFormEntity( params ) );

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute( httpPost );
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }
        else
            if (method == "GET")
            {
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString =
                        URLEncodedUtils.format( params , "utf-8" );
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet( url );

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute( httpGet );
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClientProtocolException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try
    {
        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(
                        is ,
                        "iso-8859-1" ) , 8 );
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ( ( line = reader.readLine() ) != null)
        {
            sb.append( line + "\n" );
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e( "Buffer Error" , "Error converting result " + e.toString() );
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try
    {
        jObj = new JSONObject( json );
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        Log.e( "JSON Parser" , "Error parsing data " + e.toString() );
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Using this fetch a JSON object which you can easily parse for getting necessary values!

**If the json objects has many other `jsonArray` in it then put it in a loop and parse.**